# message received from GSM contains parenthesis instead of curly braces

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

the GSM code i have been working out is up and running, I use JSON format in sending the data obtained by my sensors, but the JSON message I have been receiving contains parenthesis instead of curly braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One or both of your GSM endpoints is incapable of handling ESC prefixes according to [GSM 03.38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38). The only difference between "{" and "}" and "(" and ")" is that the former are signified by a preceding ESC which either is not being generated by the sender or is not being interpreted by the receiver.